# CSS image slideshow images next to each other

Tags: html, css, image, slider, slideshow

I am a student learning basic HTML and CSS. I made a website with a portfolio of works I have created in my digital arts class, and I created a simple CSS slideshow. The goal was to have each image on its own slide, and let it scroll through automatically. Now, I resized so they would fit when the tab was maximized, and they instead are all next to eachother on one slide.
Here is the HTML:

```css
@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 5%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="riley%20clipping%20mask%20again.jpg" style="width:10%;">
    <img src="pouya%20t%20shirt%20design.jpg" style="width:10%;">
    <img src="Bob%20ross%20is%20our%20lord%20-riley.jpg" style="width:10%;">
    <img src="Pos%20and%20neg%20riley.jpg" style="width:10%;">
    <img src="ben%20is%20trippy.jpg" style="width:10%;">
  </figure>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  Here you go.  Had to change your figures to divs and change up some parameters.

```css
@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -400%;
  }
}

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="container">
    <img src="riley%20clipping%20mask%20again.jpg">
    <img src="pouya%20t%20shirt%20design.jpg">
    <img src="Bob%20ross%20is%20our%20lord%20-riley.jpg">
    <img src="Pos%20and%20neg%20riley.jpg">
    <img src="ben%20is%20trippy.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```